# MariaDb Gone Away On Spesefic Row

Tags: mysql, mariadb

in my database when select from 2 of 10 tables, in spesefic rows , i give this message :

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

for example whene i try :

```
select * from records where id=238
```

every thing is ok , and even this:

```
select * from records where id=270
```

is ok.
but when try this one:

```
select * from records where id=239
```

return error :
[image]

i already search in stackoverflow and google for this and all refrence mention that increace buffer size and...
but i dont think this problem relate to this subjects , its seems that some data is currept the table.

p.s : engine that use is innodb
any clue please

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/repair-table/

Answer (score 1):

MySQL closes itself when a operation tries to read from a corrupted InnoDB table.

This is very annoying but is the only way I know by heart.

Is possible to recover all data in most of times, the procedure is the same for MySQL, MariaDB and XtraDB.

There is a lot of explanation on the official manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html.

But, essentially, you need to add an option named `innodb_force_recovery` on MySQL configuration file, restart MySQL and try to `SELECT` that corrupted data. This options goes from number `1` to `6`, but above `3` you could lose some data.

When you found a number that allow you to make a `SELECT` on that rows, `mysqldump` the entire table to recover after.

Depending on table state you'll need to remove the file manually before start MySQL without `innodb_force_recovery`:

```sh
rm /var/lib/mysql/myschema/corrupted_table.ibd
```

This will cause other problems, but once the database start you'll need to drop the old tablespace, create "the same table" in another database and swap the tablespaces:

```sql
USE a;
ALTER TABLE corrupted_table DISCARD TABLESPACE;
CREATE DATABASE b;
-- import the dump inside database b
-- fisically move the "ibd" file from "b" to "a"
-- mv /var/lib/mysql/a/corrupted_table.idb /var/lib/mysql/b/corrupted_table.idb
USE a;
ALTER TABLE corrupted_table IMPORT TABLESPACE;
DROP TABLE b.corrupted_table;
```